# UiPath - Activity "Click" in mouse hover menu

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

I want to click on an element in the menu that only releases that element from the mouse hover, when I put the activity "Click", the pointer disappears and the menu closes.

I intend to use the "Select Area" together with the "Click" activity!

How can I solve?

Comment: Did you use the Web Recorder feature?

Comment: I'm working with a desktop application, does Web Record work with that type of application?

Comment: It works anywhere. Sure. In browser you need a browser extension but on desktop apps it works automatically.

Comment: The problem is that the contents of the menu only appear when the mouse is over it. When I use the "Click" activity, the mouse disappears for a few seconds, which is the time for the menu to disappear, and within the activity the pointer is only available to select a click area. I need a way to leave this menu active when I am selecting the "Click" activity area

Comment: Create a screencast of that. Because in the Recorder mode you just click and it records in the background. So what you are talking cannot happen. So please show what you mean. Maybe you are not using the recorder and instead a Click activity directly?

Answer (score 1):

Once you take an click activity and Indicate on Element..

Press F2 , That will pause the automation for 3 Sec, You can now open the submenu.

Answer (score 1):

When you are about to select the Selector, press F2 to halt the selection for a couple seconds, then hover on the item to select it afterwards.

Remember that the click need to be a 'Simulate Click' to work without in background, but it doesn't always work, so if that's your case you will need to first use the 'Hover Mouse' activity to expand that panel you are trying to click.